# application for facebook business pages/tab - maximum width for embed

Tags: facebook

I am looking at creating an application for facebook business pages (e.g. restaurants).

There will be a sign-up page (to identify th business as having access to our system and to pull the appropriate content, and then, based on that, we will be displaying content under a new tab.

To determine feasibility I need to know the maximum width allowed for the iframe in which we can display the information (not critical for sign-up process). I noticed that the page layout varies under different facebook tabs. Can one choose that when integrating the iframe?

Answer (score 1):

The width of the FBML page has to be 520px so aslong as it fits within your design the it will work.

If you need any help, visit www.leamasmarketing.com and submit a form ill respond from that email.